# Alternatives to group_map

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, data-manipulation

I am curious what would be the base R code and `data.table` code that do the same work as `group_map` in `dplyr`?

For example, how to realize this code using base R and `data.table` code?

```
iris %>%
     group_by(Species) %>%
     group_map(~ lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, data = .x))
```

Many thanks!

**EDIT**
I would like to convert the entire code above to one with base R code and so if possible also get rid of the `group_by` and `%>%`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With **by** and **.SD**, the **data.table** code can work

```
  setDT(iris)[, .(list(lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, .SD))), by = .(Species)] %>% 
  as.list()
```

Similar to this question [Fit model by group using Data.Table package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29420674/fit-model-by-group-using-data-table-package)

The **%>%** is not necessary,

```
as.list(setDT(iris)[, .(list(lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, .SD))), by = .(Species)])
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer Peace. However, is there any way to not use ```dplyr``` at all including the ```group_by``` and ```%>%``` function?

Comment: As you can see, 
1.  I don't  use **dplyr**'s **group_by**. The **by** is the inner function of  **data.table**
2. **%>%** is just used to process the side effect, the core code is the third row.

Comment: Would it be possible to convert the entire code to base R code and also get rid of the ```%>%```?

Comment: Something like this?

`as.list(data.table(iris)[, .(list(lm(Petal.Length ~ Sepal.Length, .SD))), by = .(Species)])
`

Comment: Great. Thank you!